# Как получить результат SQL запроса INNER JOIN трех таблиц, в виде List<объектов(строк)> через Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

Как получить результат SQL запроса INNER JOIN трех таблиц, в виде List<объектов(строк)> через Spring Data JPA ?

Есть три таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написал запрос

```
 SELECT * FROM (CLIENTS INNER JOIN SEGMENT ON CLIENTS.SEGMENT_CD = 
 SEGMENT.SEGMENT_NAME) INNER JOIN DEPOSIT_SEGMENT ON SEGMENT.SEGMENT_ID = 
 DEPOSIT_SEGMENT.SEGMENT_ID;
```

Вот его результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу получить этот результат запроса в виде List<объектов(строк)> в java через Spring Data JPA?

Comment: а что если использовать `queryForObject` пример: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate